# Clicking anywhere triggers the button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my scene, I have this set-up:

- Game Controller

  - Level Controller
  - Main Camera
  - Event System
- Canvas
- Player

  - PlayerCanvas (Render Mode is World Space)

    - Button

I set the PlayerCanvas into the same width and height of the button. And both of them are just small. I put Debug.Log to check everytime I press the button. But somehow, it triggers the button even if I click way off the screen. Can help to explain why is this happening. Thanks!

Note: I'm trying to add a button beside the Player so that even if the Player moves, the button will just follow.

Comment: No event system in the hierarchy?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Yes, there is an event system.
And it doesn't even have a code.
But when I check the World Space Canvas, it says that "A World Space Canvas with no specified Event Camera may not register UI events correctly." Although, I have tried to attach my MainCamera, it's still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your hierarchy is wrong.
Try something like

```
Game Controller
 Level Controller
 Main Camera
 Player
Event System
Canvas (Screen Space - Overlay)
  Button
```

Not sure what Player is, but I'm sure on my hierarchy  Event System and Canvas are on the same level. And every button is son of Canvas. Not sure you can make multiple Cavas (you should not need it anyway).